# Verify receipts with in-app purchase

Tags: ios, security, in-app-purchase

Had a scenario for a company today, but I ran into an issue in my logic... went a little something like this:

(Hypothetical situation): So I have an app where users can buy my product (a real life tangible product) via an in-app purchase, and they enter their address and I ship it to them and all is well! I get the money in about a months time from Apple and they get their product within a few days.

The problem is that jail broken device thieves start "purchasing" the product without actually  spending any money, but the app thinks they did the in-app purchase so it send their info over to my server which then processes the order and I send the product, but a month later, Apple never sends me any money :o

How can I prevent this?

Comment: Apple actually forbid this in their terms and conditions.

Comment: @DavidCaunt Woah! I never knew that! Do you know if I am forbidden to sell products at all in apps or just via in-app purchases? Could I sell them via PayPal within my app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't sell physical goods using in-app purchases. From apple guidelines:

> You must deliver your digital good or service within your app. Do not
>   use In-App Purchase to sell real-world goods and services.

But hypothetically - if you were able to - you could (and should) easily validate the receipt with apple's verification server. [See apple's documentation.](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/General/ValidateAppStoreReceipt/Chapters/ValidateRemotely.html)

Comment: Wow! So like DropBox couldn't even sell server space :o Thats crazy haha! Okay, well thankyou for the link to server verification :) That's great for like a magazine app selling digital download subscriptions right? :)